# C# .NET async await return type

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, return, async-await

Just hoping someone could clear up return types when using `async` and `await` in C#. I understand that you have three return types being `Task<T>`, `Task` and `void`.

From trying to learn about this I have read you should only use `void` in special circumstances (Event Handlers) and if you are changing a synchronous method to an `async` method then you should change a `void` keyword to `Task`.

My question is do I need a `Task` return type even though the code is completely independent and the result doesn't matter for the continuation? Say for example I use the asynchronous method to push some information to a web service.

I have created a small example to help explain:

```
private void CallingMethod()
{
    AsyncMethod();
    AsyncTaskMethod(); // any difference between doing these? (not exc handling)

    var task = AsyncTaskMethod(); // should I do anything with this task
                                  // before I continue? Or is it simply 
                                  // just to show the user that it's async??

    // continue with unrelated code that doesnt require task or any code from above
}

private async void AsyncMethod() // is void okay?
{
    await LongRunningMethod();

    // do other stuff
}

private async Task AsyncTaskMethod() // or should it be Task?
{
    await LongRunningMethod();

    // do other stuff
}

private async Task LongRunningMethod()
{
    // do long running code
}
```

My application has a lot of methods like so:

```
private void BigMethod()
{
    DoStuff();

    DoMoreStuff();

    AsyncMethod(); // is this right? Or should I have the task declaration too?

    UnrelatedStuff();
}

private async Task AsyncMethod() // should this return task?
{
    var result = await GetUserId();

    if (result == null)
        return;

    MyUserId = result;
}

private async Task<int> GetUserId()
{
    // do long running code
    return 1;
}
```

If it's not clear, by all means just say and I'll try to tidy it up a bit. Thanks guys.

EDIT:

```
private void CallingMethod()
{
    AsyncMethod();
}

private async void AsyncMethod()
{
    await LongRunningMethod();
}

private async Task LongRunningMethod()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
    });

    MessageBox.Show("Done!");
}
```

In response to the first comment, the above `CallingMethod()` does not use async/await and it happily sleeps for 4 seconds without locking up the UI thread, then pops up the message box. What's the problem?

Comment: The CallingMethod() should use `async` and `await`. Without that the question makes little sense.

Comment: Note that "async" is not the same as "parellel": the code after the "await" line is not executed until that line is done awaiting.

Comment: It doesn't have to? Please check edit

Comment: @Murphybro2: You shouldn't have a bunch of "fire and forget"-style methods; if you do, there's something wrong with the design. With synchronous code, you would just call `F()` directly; with asynchronous code, the usual pattern is to call `await FAsync()`. If you find yourself needing to do `FAsync()` a lot without `await`, it's a sign that something is likely wrong with what you're trying to do. (And this question does not have sufficient context to diagnose this design-level problem).

Comment: Hi @StephenCleary, thanks for the reply. I got slightly confused whilst writing this question and didn't correctly replicate how my application is using async/await! I was mistaking async calls with await directly infront of them as "fire and forget" for some reason! I'll put my hand up for that one..

Answer (score 3):

You don't **have to** use `Task` when a method returns `void`, but it is indeed preferred, for several reasons:

1. Async methods that return a `Task` (or `Task<T>`) have their exceptions put on the returned `Task`, so calling methods can check (when they see fit) whether the `Task` was faulted or not.
2. `Async void` methods have their exceptions thrown directly on the calling synchronization context, making it nearly (*nearly* because you can still use global exception handlers, but that's unmaintainable for big applications) impossible to handle exceptions on them on a deterministic manner.
3. You basically can't test any `async void` methods that may throw an exception
4. `async void` methods are assumed to be complete when they are run by the caller. This can introduce many problems (in fact, there are many problems with event handlers when you try to convert an existing library to async: go ahead, get a third-party relatively complex winforms library and try to make your event handlers async, you'll see the havoc it creates!).
5. There is no reasonable way to determine when an `async void` method has finished (you could make your own `SynchronizationContext`, but that's something definitely complex)
6. You can't configure an `async void` call (you can't use `ConfigureAwait` on it), so the continuation context is always the caller's synchronization context.

So...

**TL;DR:** don't use `async void` unless you can't avoid it (that is: with event handlers that expect a `void` signature). There are reasons for it. Use `async Task` if you don't expect a result.

Comment: Okay, so I have this code:

public void TryToCatchMethod()
        {
            try
            {
                MyAsyncMethod();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //tha catch is never called
                Debug.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
            }
        }
        public async void MyAsyncMethod()
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

When the exception is thrown the application crashes, unhandled exception. So how would I change it to capture the exception?

Comment: I apologise for the format, see Radin Gospodinovs answer for the formatted version

Comment: Make the async method return `Task`, and have the caller method `await` it: [check it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zU93YA). Make it *async all the way down* (and while we are at it, change the caller method to return `Task` too)

Comment: Okay I see. So whenever I use an async method, I should make every call before it async too?

Comment: Not **necessarily**, but if you don't (and want to check for errors), you'll have to wait for the task in the caller (otherwise, how are you going to check for errors?). You can do something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JKEKMR . You'll have to check then for `AggregateException` then (and check the `InnerException` to get the exception that was thrown in the actual async method). Exceptions in `async` callers are not aggregated, but if you call them from a non-async one, they are (and there could be several exceptions if you are waiting for many tasks, for example)

Comment: This all makes for an awkward situation which I'm sure many people will have different opinions on.. for example what happens if I'm calling a method using ICommand, I can't change the return type of that to Task!

Comment: @Murphybro2: No, but you can [minimize the `async void` method to a single line, and treat it in your code as `async Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx).

Comment: @Murphybro2 I'd implement my `ICommand` and have the `Execute` method (an `async void` out of necessity) call my own async method returning `Task`. You can even have your `interface IAsyncCommand : ICommand` and have some `Task ExecuteAsync()` signature on it. The `void Execute` method would just be a placeholder (at least that's how I'd implement it)

Comment: Actually, that seems to be what they are doing on @StephenCleary 's link, sorry, answered here while the link was opening on a background tab :-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot await methods that return `void` and also one of the main reasons is that the caller of a void-returning async method can't catch exceptions that are thrown from the async method. Try that:

```
  public void TryToCatchMethod() {
    try {
      MyAsyncMethod();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      //tha catch is never called
      Debug.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
    }
  }
  public async void MyAsyncMethod() {
    throw new Exception();
  }
```

Comment: Okay thanks, thats great. So whats the alternative? Replacing void with Task? Doing so stops the exception crashing the program, but it doesnt appear to be caught either?

Comment: Replace it with this:  public async Task MyAsyncMethod() {
      throw new Exception();
    } and then await it,  you will see how the catch block will be executed.