# Task return type with and without Async

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I little bit confused on the behavior of the `async` keyword.

Lets say I have 2 methods,

```
public async Task DoSomething1()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I m doing something:" + i);
        }
    });
}
```

And

```
public Task DoSomething2()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I m doing something:" + i);
        }
    });
}
```

From my understanding both methods are awaitable. But when I write a method that has a `Task` return type without the `async` keyword I need to return a `Task` otherwise the compiler generates an error. Its a common thing that a method should return its type. But when I use it with the `async` keyword the compiler generates another error that you can't return a `Task`. So what does it mean? I am totally confused here.

Comment: When you use `async` it's going to turn your code into a state machine that runs code until it hit's an `await` and then put the code after the `await` into a continuation and ultimately wraps the return type up into a `Task` for `void` or `Task<int>` for `int`.

Comment: I agree this is probably a duplicate question, but not a duplicate of `return await`.  There must be another one @Fruchtzwerg.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this experience has turned me a little sour.  I don't understand the down votes, I expect that it _is_ a duplicate question, but the wrong duplicate was linked.  Also what about the OP?  Did their question even get answered?  Did SO even help?

Comment: @Servy, please help me out.  The correct duplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808644/c-sharp-net-async-await-return-type.  Can you fix the issue please?  I don't think y'all took the time to actually understand the OP's question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### General Async Info

If you use `await` in your code, you are required to use the `async` keyword on the method.

If you use `async` and want to return an actual type, you can declare that your method returns the type as a generic Task like this `Task<int>`.

Here are the valid return types for an `async` method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types

1. `Task<TResult>`, for an async method that returns a value.
2. `Task`, for an async method that performs an operation but returns no value.
3. `void`, for an event handler.

### A new answer August 2022

TL;DR - The return type is automatically wrapped in a Task.

I was receiving downvotes on this so I re-read the question in more detail and got to the root of it.  It's not about the return type in the signature of the method.  Its about the return **value**; why do I not need to return an explicit `Task` type?  *(Also it is not a duplicate question!)*

Anyway, let's look at this method:

```
public Task TaskMethod() 
{
    return Task.CompletedTask;        
}
```

This seems pretty normal and what we are used to in C#.  You declare the return type and return an object of that type.  Easy.  (In fact the "lowered" code is the exact same.)

Now for the async case.

```
public async Task MethodAsync() 
{
    return Task.CompletedTask;  
}
```

This generates a compile error: `error CS1997: Since 'C.MethodAsync()' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task<T>'?`

OK, then we can't return a task directly, let's do the right thing.  It is easier to see this example if we return something so, let's return int.

```
public async Task<int> MethodAsync() 
{
    return 1;
}
```

*(This method gives a warning that we are using async without await, but ignore this for now.)*

The lowered code is **complicated**, but you can see that a state machine will be generated.  The MethodAsync looks like this:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <MethodAsync>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    public int <>1__state;

    public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int> <>t__builder;

    public C <>4__this;

    private void MoveNext()
    {
        int num = <>1__state;
        int result;
        try
        {
            result = 1;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            <>1__state = -2;
            <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
            return;
        }
        <>1__state = -2;
        <>t__builder.SetResult(result);
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in MoveNext
        this.MoveNext();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    private void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in SetStateMachine
        this.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }
}

[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<MethodAsync>d__0))]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public Task<int> MethodAsync()
{
    <MethodAsync>d__0 stateMachine = new <MethodAsync>d__0();
    stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int>.Create();
    stateMachine.<>4__this = this;
    stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
    stateMachine.<>t__builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
    return stateMachine.<>t__builder.Task;
}
```

And you can see the Task here is automatically returned in the public method.  The state machine implements the method body.

You can see that the actual value returned is the int from `<>t__builder` wrapped in a Task.

To see the lowered code yourself, you can try it in https://sharplab.io.

Also after writing all this I found another answer that explains it in a different way.  Guess who wrote that answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37647093/1804678

Comment: I added more relevant questions in the list of duplicates, to address your statement *"Also it is not a duplicate question!"*. Like the [async await return Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191512/async-await-return-task). The current question is certainly a duplicate. Everyone is confused with the return type of `async` methods, when they see them for the first time.

Comment: Hi @TheodorZoulias, It is more about _how_ a method that says it returns a Task<> returns that Task without seeing it explicitly in the method body.  Honestly, I did not see a duplicate for this in any of the questions I've seen.  Certainly, there is general confusion, but this answers a very specific aspect.

Comment: I think that the OP is more interested to learn about the rules that govern the C# language, than about the technicalities of how these rules are implemented by the C# compiler. The specification of a language comes first, and the implementation comes second. You don't start implementing a compiler before having specified the rules of the language.

Answer (score 2):

> (...) “async”. This keyword
>   allows that inside the method the word “await” can be used, and
>   modifies how its result is handled by the method. That’s it.
>
> The method runs synchronously until it finds the word “await” and that
>   word is the one that takes care of asynchrony. “Await” is an operator
>   that receives a parameter: an awaitable (an asynchronous operation)
>   behaves in this way:

From [here](http://www.hexacta.com/2016/06/01/task-run-vs-async-await/)